# Question about factoring/condensing equation rules

Tags: factoring

I have the equation $x^2 - 6x = 72$ and then $x^2 - 6x - 72 = 0$ that's supposed to turn into $(x-12)(x+6)$. 72/6 = 12. So could just do that with any equation that? Divide the end thing with the middle coefficient of x to get the thing for the first set of parentheses? Or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

$ x^2+4x+4=0$

$(x+2)\cdot (x+2)=0$

$4÷4\neq 2$

It was coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a coincidence.

When the solutions are $a,b$:

- the middle term is $-a-b$ (here it is $-(-6)-12 = -6)$)
- the end term is $ab$ (here: $-6\times 12 = -72$).

The formula 
$$
-\frac{a+b}{ab}
$$is not a solution in general.

---

This is a coincidence because here you have $-a-b = a$.